# use android modules in xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, module

How do You use pre-built module codes from Maven or j-center Repositories in an android xamarin project?

**To be more specific:**

I want to use this free module as a date picker :

https://github.com/alirezaafkar/SunDatePicker

I have read this page :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

But since this module is not just a `jar` file , I think the method explained in the page wont be useful.

Comment: Just create a `.aar` library project in Android Studio, add the SunDatePicker as a gradle dependency and build it. Then create a `Xamarin.Android` binding project to place a C# wrapper on the `.aar`. I do it all the time, works really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an .aar library project in Android Studio, add the SunDatePicker as a gradle dependency and build it. Then create a Xamarin.Android binding project to place a C# wrapper on the .aar. I do it all the time, works really well.

Thanks to SushiHangover.