# How to embed Fragment inside an Activity xamarin android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-activity, interface

I have a main application. My module-fragment should be embedded into this application. I need to create class with function "`createDashboard(Flistener listener, int resourceLayoutId, Context context)`"

Flistener listener - A listener for my module for interacting with the application.

resourceLayoutId - The layout resource to whom my module will add the fragment (Will be a FrameLayout in XML)

Context - A context for adding fragment.

How can I implement this function? How should I return the view with it's functionality?

This is my code until now:

```
public class Manager
{
    void createDashboard(FListener fibgtoListener, int resourceLayoutId , Context context)
    {

    }
}
interface FListener
{
    void updateParentHeaderVisibilty(bool isVisible);
    void sendData(string data, string requestId);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, what will  the `createDashboard` return?

Comment: Hi, by `module`, do you want to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403849/use-android-modules-in-xamarin-project)? Or you just want create a class in your project and create a fragment by the class? I can't understand your question very clearly.

Comment: Yes, I need to create a .JAR. The main application is native, written in Java and android studio. In this application there is an entry point(some button). When this button is clicked my application (module .JAR) must be loaded. So createDashboard - method is called when the user is pressing the entry point in main menu of application.

Comment: It is a native project? Not Xamarin.Android?

Comment: My app is xamarin-android. The main application is native

Comment: My module must be loaded as a fragment into main application and it must be communicated with each others

Comment: Sorry, do you want to add Xamarin.Android in to main application(native)?

Comment: Yes. There is a library that can embed xamarin into native

Comment: In your module, you can create a fragment, and in your `createDashboard`, just new it, and return. In your main application, use this module's Manager to create the fragment. This can't work?

Comment: Would you mind give me a demo?

Comment: I gave you if I had . I am only have this kind specifications that  mentioned above. The main application is just black box for me.

Comment: Hi, I think you are talking about `Android plug-in` or `Android modular`, it is right? You want your module to be a plug added by main application? But if you have the `resourceLayoutId` in your main application, why do you need to the plug, you can create the fragment in the main application.

Comment: Ok. Can you show me an example?